# Laravel blade compare two date

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I would like to compare 2 dates. So I create a condition like this in my template blade:

```
@if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($contrat->date_facturation)->format('d/m/Y') < $dateNow)
    <td class="danger">
        {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contrat->date_facturation)->format('d/m/Y') }}
    </td>
@else
    <td>
        {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contrat->date_facturation)->format('d/m/Y') }}
    </td>
@endif
```

My variable $dateNow has the same format on my value in $contract->date_facturation

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDr8J.png)

It add a red background on the date 25/02/2018 while the date is not less than the variable $contract->date_facturation

Do you have any idea of ​​the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to compare two date strings. PHP don't know how to compare date strings.

`Carbon::format()` returns a string. You shoud convert your dates to a Carbon object (using parse) and use Carbon's comparison methods, as described on [Carbon Docs (Comparison)](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison).

For your example, you should do:

```
// Note that for this work, $dateNow MUST be a carbon instance.
@if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($contrat->date_facturation)->lt($dateNow))
    <td class="danger">
        {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contrat->date_facturation)->format('d/m/Y') }}
    </td>
@else
    <td>
        {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contrat->date_facturation)->format('d/m/Y') }}
    </td>
@endif
```

Also your code looks repetitive, and assuming that `$dateNow` is a variable with current date, you can use `Carbon::isPast()` method, so rewriting your code, it becomes:

```
@php($date_facturation = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contrat->date_facturation))
@if ($date_facturation->isPast())
    <td class="danger">
@else
    <td>
@endif
        {{ $date_facturation->format('d/m/Y') }}
    </td>
```

This makes your code less repetitive and faster, since you parse the date once, instead of twice.

Also if you want your code better, use [Eloquent's Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators), so you won't need to parse dates everytime that you need on your views.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse both dates, change your code to:

```
<td class="{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($contrat->date_facturation) < Carbon\Carbon::parse($dateNow) ? 'danger' : '' }}">
    {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contrat->date_facturation)->format('d/m/Y') }}
</td>
```

Alternatively, you can use the [date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators). In this case you'll not need to parse dates.

Answer (score 2):

### Compare date in blade template

I used this method of Carbon:

```
@foreach($earnings as $data)

@if($data->created_at ==  Carbon\Carbon::today())
      <tr class="alert alert-success">
@else
      <tr>
@endif
  ....
@endforeach
```

[More Details](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)