# Laravel Date Compare Not Working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to compare two dates in laravel. I don't know how to do that. I am trying this code. But not getting the the result i want.

```js
 @if((2018-06-15)>(2018-05-15))
            If part is Not Working
            @else
             Don't know why else part is working
            @endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel blade compare two date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469816/laravel-blade-compare-two-date)

Answer (score 0):

Well i have found a solution. The dates should be in type of string like this.

```js
@if(('2018-06-15')>('2018-05-15'))
            Now If part is Working
            @else
             Else part
            @endif
```